# newUploadPhotoRequest fails with errorCode 324

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a file (from byte array) to Facebook using Facebook for Android SDK 3.0. I have added permission `publish_actions` as shown in the SDK samples. Still, I get the following error on upload:

*{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 324, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#324) Requires upload file}*

Google gives me nothing on this one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the relevant code?  This is the code I use to upload photos using the Android SDK, and I have verified that it works:

```
   Request request6 = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
            session,
            ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.picture)).getBitmap(), callback6);
    RequestAsyncTask task6 = new RequestAsyncTask(request6);
    task6.execute();
```

This is supplying the method with a `BitMap`, it seems like you're calling the method that takes in a `File`.  You have to choose either to supply a `BitMap` or a valid `File` object.

Comment: Stupid me. Image was `null`... thanks for verifying my code though :)

Comment: I am trying to upload multiple photos , using the same code above, but running into errors. I am using requestBatch, passing it the request6 and then asyncexecute.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I discovered that Bitmap created with config Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8 are not valid for newUploadPhotoRequest. I tried with Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 and it works.